# JQuery undefined on success - asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

whenever I run this script I get undefined on success.I'm trying to load the datagrid based on textbox input. 
I read other topics similar to this but none of them worked for me.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function bindGrid() {
    var pageurl = '<%=ResolveUrl("Default.aspx/bindGrid1") %>';
    var gv = $("#<%=gvFunctions.ClientID%>").val();
    var idno = $("#<%=txtIDNO.ClientID%>").val();
    var name = $("#<%=txtName.ClientID%>").val();
    var tel = $("#<%=txtTel.ClientID%>").val();

    var parameter = {
        "gv":gv,
        "idno": idno,
        "name": name,
        "tel": tel
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: pageurl,
        data: JSON.stringify(parameter),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnSuccess,
        failure: function(response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
    });
}

function OnSuccess(response) {
    alert(response.d);
}
</script>
```

Here's the code for the function bindGrid1

```
[WebMethod]
public static void bindGrid1(GridView gv, String idno, String name, String tel)
{ 
     DataSet ds;
     SqlDataAdapter SqlAda;
     SqlConnection con = getConnection();
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     cmd.CommandText = "mysproc";
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@IDNO", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = idno;
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = name;
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@Tel", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tel;
     cmd.Connection = con;
     try
     {
         con.Open();
         gv.EmptyDataText = "No data.";

         SqlAda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
         ds = new DataSet();

         SqlAda.Fill(ds);

         gv.DataSource = ds;
         gv.DataBind();
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        myMessageBox(ex.Message);
     }
     finally
     {
         con.Close();
         con.Dispose();
     }
}
```

I would appreciate any kind of help.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What exactly is `undefined`?

Comment: Where does your script block terminate? Post the full <script> tag.

Comment: @eisbehr "Undefined" is the alert I get.

Comment: @ben3000 thank you for the correction, something went wrong with copy/paste. I updated the code

Comment: Well, for me your code is totally correct and should work. The only thing is, are you sure `response` has a property `d`? Try `console.log(response)` in your `OnSuccess` function to see what you get there.

Comment: @eisbehr I tried that, I don't get an error message but I get no result from the function. I edited my post and added the function  bindGrid1, in case there is a problem with that part of my code.

Comment: And what did you saw in your console?

Comment: POST 
XHR 
http://localhost/Admin/Default.aspx/bindGrid1 [HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 8ms]

Answer (score 0):

Your Webmethod must have return something.

Here I set string message return.

```
[WebMethod]
public static string bindGrid1(GridView gv, String idno, String name, String tel)
{ 
string message="";
     DataSet ds;
     SqlDataAdapter SqlAda;
     SqlConnection con = getConnection();
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     cmd.CommandText = "mysproc";
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@IDNO", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = idno;
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = name;
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@Tel", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tel;
     cmd.Connection = con;
     try
     {
         con.Open();
         gv.EmptyDataText = "No data.";
         SqlAda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
         ds = new DataSet();
         SqlAda.Fill(ds);
         gv.DataSource = ds;
         gv.DataBind();
       message ="Success";
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        myMessageBox(ex.Message);
       message ="Error";
     }
     finally
     {
         con.Close();
         con.Dispose();
     }
     return  message; 

}
```

Comment: I changed the code but I'm still getting the "undefined" message.